# Download flickr images of specific url

Tags: python, flickr

I want to download some images from flickr. For example, I have this link http://www.flickr.com/photos/tonynetone/3717759677/ and I want to save in my disk this image of size large with a specific name. The documentation in this [link](http://stuvel.eu/media/flickrapi-docs/documentation/) did not helped me a lot. Could you please some one give an example of python code?

Thank you.

PS: windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need a pure Python solution?  How do you like a Bash one-liner like this?

```
$ curl http://www.flickr.com/photos/tonynetone/3717759677/ | egrep 'http:\\/\\/[^"]*jpg' -o | sed -e 's@\\@@g'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  177k    0  177k    0     0   164k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  309k
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/3717759677_4a520a1dbb_s.jpg
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/3717759677_4a520a1dbb_q.jpg
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/3717759677_4a520a1dbb_t.jpg
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/3717759677_4a520a1dbb_m.jpg
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/3717759677_4a520a1dbb.jpg
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/3717759677_97b2ab3b4d_o.jpg
```

By the way there's no "large" option for the photo you referred to

- http://www.flickr.com/photos/tonynetone/3717759677/sizes/m/in/photostream/

Perhaps you meant "original" (`_o`) ?

### Update

```
import urllib2, re

def download(url, save_name):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    img_url = re.findall(r'http:[^" \\:]*_b\.jpg', html)[0]

    with open(save_name, "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(urllib2.urlopen(img_url).read())

download('http://www.flickr.com/photos/91440301@N03/9679566882/sizes/l/', 'elephant.jpg')
```

Usage notes

1. If there is no "large" option (a photo whose filename ends with `_b.jpg`), it will just raise an exception (perhaps `IndexError`.)  Please catch it by yourself.
2. Supports only `.jpg`
3. Please determine `save_name` by yourself.

Comment: Yes in this specific image there is not large _option_. Unfortunately, I am not a linux user.

Comment: Well, I can write Python for you if you don't have Linux tools, but what about the lack of "large"...  Do you just want to give up?

Comment: In some images there is an option for large images. The image can be an option.

Comment: For example, look at this [image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/91440301@N03/9679566882/sizes/l/), there is a large image for download. If you can with python code python code great!

Answer (score 2):

I usually download an image as below

```
import urllib2

def get_image(url, image_save_name):
    try:
        image = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        with open(image_save_name + '.' + url.split('.')[-1], 'wb') as image_file:
            image_file.write(image)
            image_file.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print e

get_image('http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2277/2046712361_77f514172f_z.jpg', 'image_save_name')
```

Comment: I do not have the full link `*.jpg` just the link above. Also, I think with this code you do not know which size of the image you download.

Comment: It is very easy go to the link study the source code (use firebug) see the pattern each image of different size will have a unique identifier (e.g. http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2277/2046712361_77f514172f_n.jpg). download the page  http://www.flickr.com/photos/tonynetone/3717759677/ scrap the page with beautiful soup get the link for the size of image you need and download the image

Comment: @Sar009 I recommend you to migrate to the `with open(path) as var:` idiom from calling `close()` manually.

Comment: @nodakai thank you very much. it was always in my mind to check what is the difference between with open and open but i missed it always is there any other difference in both

Comment: @Sar009 (1) you are **guaranteed** to `close()` the file even when an exception is thrown (2) the scope of the file variable is visibly clear;  after all there's little drawbacks in switching to the `with` syntax.  I think it's like riding a bicycle;  once you get used to it you just feel it's more comfortable than before.
Btw I like your idea of copying the file extension of the online image file to `image_save_name`